# rm: cannot remove Input/output error in part of folder in a permanently mounted NTFS drive

Tags: rm, ntfs, ntfs-3g

NTFS: Input/output error

I was experimenting with HDF5 installation from a permanently mounted NTFS data partition so lots of deletion etc. Now part of the folder (containing some codes etc.) is not deleting and showing the above error. I have already NTFS-3g etc. but only have windows on virtualbox (from which also can not delete).
Thanks for all the help!

I am on CentOS 7.

Comment: How is that NTFS partition mounted on your Windows VM?

Comment: @Julie: The OP has tages `nrfs-3g` that means he has used it ntfs-3g for mounting the filesystem. hope he reply to confirm

Comment: I used centos 7 fstab entry 'UUID=4A6C45276C450F5F /mnt/Various ntfs defaults        0 0' to mount. In VM win 7 it is mounted as shared folder

Comment: Sometimes, you can [fix NTFS partitions easily using Window 10](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/570616/40149).

Answer (score 2):

This means your filesystem is damaged, Input/Output errors during filesystem access attempts generally mean hardware issues.

Type dmesg and check for log. it might be because of connection to it is failing, it'll be noted there.

is it mounting it via ntfs or ntfs-3g ? As I recall, the legacy ntfs driver had no stable write support and was largely abandoned when it turned out ntfs-3g was significantly more stable and secure.

Comment: it is mounted as 'UUID=4A6C45276C450F5F /mnt/Various ntfs defaults 0 0' . should I make it ntfs-3g?

Comment: @ankhi first of all you should fix it (with `chkdsk` in Windows).

Comment: I have only virtualbox windows hence I cant use chkdsk

Answer (score 0):

Read about [mount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) / [umount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/umount) (man pages)

In my case directory had be to unmount first, to be eligible to be deleted itself or its subdirectories/files

`sudo umount -f /media/sami/OS\somewindows_folder`

Then simply `sudo rm -rf /media/sami/OS\somewindows_folder` worked for me

Comment: This is absolutely not an issue of mounting. You're not deleting anything on the actual external drive since you've just unmounted your drive. You are simply running `rm` on an empty/nonexisting path (since nothing is mounted at `/media/sami/OS` anymore) but it fails silently since you're using the `-f` switch. This consequently accomplishes absolutely nothing. **You** definitely should read about what mounting is.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem,too.Some topics tell me that I should mount this disk on Win and rm it and clean the trash.I tried but failed.

But,I rm this files parent folder (on Linux `rm -rf xxx` ),and solved this problem.

U can try this way but remember to copy the import files or folders in parent folder.