# removing a directory

Tags: linux, rm

I'm trying to remove a directory called `cc` by running the command `rm -rf cc`, but it has trouble removing a file inside the directory.

I get the following error:

```
rm: cannot remove 'boy.mp4' : Input/output error
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Is this on an `ntfs` filesystem by any chance?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [rm: cannot remove Input/output error in part of folder in a permanently mounted NTFS drive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292507/rm-cannot-remove-input-output-error-in-part-of-folder-in-a-permanently-mounted).

Comment: yes it is ntfs filesystem. it is a directory on an external hard drive

Answer (score 0):

Your file system probably has some errors on it. If it's NTFS, you can run `chkdsk` on Windows to fix it, otherwise, you should try running `fsck` on it.

`fsck` can't run on an active file system, so if the file is on it, you'll need to boot to a live system to fix it, or force the system to do it on boot with `sudo touch /forcefsck`